# Getting error on ubuntu 10 ec2 server while apt install

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

sudo apt install tasksel

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

**E: The package libopencv-video2.4v5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

Answer (score 0):

> I'd recommend : sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libopencv-video* && 
>   sudo apt-get update

- sometimes it needs the machine to be restarted

Also you could try :

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get autoremove
apt-get purge libopencv-video*
apt-get purge
apt-get clean
```

if apt didn't work you can also manually download .deb file and install it using `dpkg -i file.deb`

- Note: pick the file based on your ubuntu version and arch
  https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libopencv-video2.4